# How do you order the display of BindingResult errors according to the order of the fields on the page?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, bean-validation

I am using the hibernate implementation of jsr303 for server side validation.  When `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>` is returned I immediately add the errors to a `BindingResult` for display on the page.  I display the errors with a `form:errors` tag all in one location.  The errors display on the page in any random order.  Is there any way to coax Spring into displaying the errors according to the order of the fields on the page?

Comment: Could you post the code that adds the errors from the Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> to the BindingResult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the field errors using a custom `Comparator`:

```
private static final Comparator<FieldError> FIELD_ORDER_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<FieldError>() {

    // Your fields, ordered in the way they appear in the form
    private static final List<String> FIELDS_WITH_ORDER = ImmutableList.of("field1", "field2");

    @Override
    public int compare(FieldError fe1, FieldError fe2) {

        String field1 = fe1.getField();
        String field2 = fe2.getField();

        int field1Index = FIELDS_WITH_ORDER.indexOf(field1);
        int field2Index = FIELDS_WITH_ORDER.indexOf(field2);

        return NumberUtils.compare(field1Index, field2Index);
    }
});

...

List<FieldError> fieldErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
Collections.sort(fieldErrors, FIELD_ORDER_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: Thats not what Coder is asking . Coder has JSR303 Validation in Hibernate and they get executed based on their order in class not in the order of Fields on the Webpage . Good Question would like to see answer myself.

Comment: He said he (programmaticaly) adds the errors from the Hibernate Validator results in the BindingResult object (using BindingResult.reject() for example), so I don't think the solution is "tied" to JSR 303 or Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Yes, this solution would accomplish what I need.  But it seems like a lot of code for what I thought would have a simple out of the box solution.

Comment: You can wrap the adding of errors from the validator to the BindingResult code and the sorting in a static method, so you will have only one line of code, something like addValidationErrors(Collection<ConstraintViolation<?>>, BindingResult).

Comment: Today I stumbled on this problem, but the default implementation of `BindingResult` returns an unmodifiable list, so the sort does not work.